# Why don't listeners work on the textview in this file?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I want to get from one fragment to other fragment by clicking on titles of elements. I have decided to use deeplinks. My code works in other files of this module. However it doesn't work here. Listeners just do not work. But android studio doesn't detect any problems with my code, no errors or warnings. Below I'll give TaskItemFragment where my code doesn't work. I would appreciate your help!

TaskItemFragment

```
package com.sinx.task

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.setFragmentResult
import androidx.navigation.NavDeepLinkRequest
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.sinx.task.Constants.TASK_BUNDLE_KEY
import com.sinx.task.Constants.TASK_REQUEST_KEY
import com.sinx.taskList.databinding.ItemTaskManagerBinding


class TaskItemFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: ItemTaskManagerBinding? = null
    private val binding: ItemTaskManagerBinding
        get() = checkNotNull(_binding)



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = ItemTaskManagerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        with(binding) {

            textViewTask.setOnClickListener{
                val request = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
                    .fromUri(INNER_TASK_URI.toUri())
                    .build()
                findNavController().navigate(request)

                val nameTask = binding.textViewTask.text.toString()
                setFragmentResult(
                    TASK_REQUEST_KEY,
                    bundleOf(TASK_BUNDLE_KEY to nameTask))

            }
            textViewTaskDate.setOnClickListener{
                val request = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
                    .fromUri(INNER_TASK_URI.toUri())
                    .build()
                findNavController().navigate(request)
            }
        }
        }




    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    companion object {
        private const val INNER_TASK_URI = "app://task.innerTaskFragment"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, the TextView is not declared as clickable `android:clickable="true"`, hence the event never calls your listener.

Comment: it is interesting guess. I'll check it soon. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work